# How do I filter in a playlist in the new Spotify interface (on mac)?

Tags: macos, spotify

Up until last week I was able to hit Cmd+F in a playlist in Spotify to quickly filter inside it. After I updated it last week this doesn't seem to work anymore.

Is it still possible to search/filter in a playlist and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest update to Spotify, which brought it above version 1.x, **removed this feature completely**, along with many, *many* other features. In that version, it's currently not possible to do this anymore. However, Spotify has mentioned that this feature [will return in future versions](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Live-Ideas/Desktop-Bring-back-search-inside-Playlists-amp-Songs-tab/idi-p/1039674), though they don't give any specific ETA or version number for the return of the feature.

The recommendation here (and if you find yourself missing any of the removed features), is to downgrade back to the last version, 0.9.x, and simply ignore the banner prompt to upgrade. Spotify directs all downgrade requests to this list: [Mac Users](http://mac.filehorse.com/download-spotify/old-versions/) / [PC Users](http://www.filehorse.com/download-spotify/old-versions/)